# how to find div with class inside in li with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this HTML code

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">test1</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test4</a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

that div.sub-menu has hidden in css.
i want when hover in a find div that inside in parent li and show it,
i try in jquery but when hover in a tag show two sub-menu div,
i want when hover in test1 show div.sub-menu that have 1,2,3,4
and when hover in test4 show div.sub-menu that have a,b,c,d

Comment: Please post your Javascript code, then we can help you fix it.

Comment: What you have tried with `js/jquery`? Plz post some javascript code too, although you can find many answers with similar question here or you can google too.

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you add more details to it

Comment: Try this: http://code-tricks.com/simple-css-drop-down-menu/ another one with Jquery and CSS based: http://code-tricks.com/dropdown-menu-with-css-and-jquery-including-css-arrows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply hide/show the `sub-menu` on `mouseover`/`mouseout`:

**Javascript**

```
$("li").mouseover(function(){
    $("ul", this).show();
});

$("li").mouseout(function(){
    $("ul", this).hide();
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/EDufY/

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a handler for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events that manipulates the associated sub-menu, for example like this:

```
$(document)
   .on("mouseenter", "ul > li > a", function() {
      $(this).siblings(".sub-menu").show();
   })
   .on("mouseleave", "ul > li", function() {
     $(this).children("a").next(".sub-menu").hide();
   });
```

This snippet installs delegated event handlers that show and hide the sub-menus -- note that the "hide" trigger is different from the "show" trigger because we don't want the menu to disappear as soon as the mouse pointer moves off the anchor. **[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/2zv37/)**.

However depending on the desired result you might also be able to do this with pure CSS, e.g.

```
ul > li > a + .sub-menu { display: none }
ul > li:hover > a + .sub-menu { display: inline-block }
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/PhfTX/1/)**.

Both versions are structured so that they work also for nested sub-menus.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to display menu on hover effect of li then i think u don't need javascript.

if u change css then it is posiible.

write your css like.

```
  .sub-menu
  {
    display:none;
  }
  li:hover .sub-menu
  {
     display:block
  }
```

And you have multilevel menu then give them id and repate above procedure

Answer (score 0):

Try this with slide effect, http://jsfiddle.net/SmtQf/1/

```
$(function () {
   $('ul li').hover(
      function () {
          $('.sub-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(); /*slideDown the subitems on mouseover*/
      }, function () {
          $('.sub-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideUp();  /*slideUp the subitems on mouseout*/
   });
});
```